# Jquery Tooltip with hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, tooltip

i have a small Tooltip Script when the user hover a block the Tooltip will be shown and if the user leave the block the tooltip is hidden.

**But i want also when the user hover over the tooltip the tooltip stay until the user leaves the tooltip or the hover block.**

here is my javascript without the hover over the Tooltip:

```
$( "#hover, .tooltip" ).on('mouseenter', function() { 
   $( ".tooltip" ).fadeToggle( 400, function() {
       // Animation complete.
    });
});

$( ".tooltip, #hover" ).on('mouseleave', function() {
      $( ".tooltip" ).fadeToggle( 400, function() {
         // Animation complete.
      });
});
```

Here is a small Fiddle without the second part:
http://jsbin.com/vocirucawoje/1/edit

Comment: I guess, it is working as expected, if not, can you point me , what you need?

Comment: almost, the tooltip flickers when you hover the tooltip because i leave the hover box a short time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use stop() to stop the animation.

```
$( "#hover, .tooltip" ).on('mouseenter', function() { 
   $( ".tooltip" ).stop().fadeToggle( 400, function() {
       // Animation complete.
    });
});

$( ".tooltip, #hover" ).on('mouseleave', function() {
      $( ".tooltip" ).stop().fadeToggle( 400, function() {
         // Animation complete.
      });
});
```

Comment: is there a nice way for a delay on fadeOut? i tried something like that but than i have these flickers again:
`$( ".tooltip, .inner-container" ).on('mouseleave', function() {
      $( ".tooltip" ).stop().delay(800).fadeOut( 400, function() {
         // Animation complete.
      });
});`

Comment: Please try to use setTimeout function. Here's the official comments of delay, "The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.".  See http://api.jquery.com/delay/ for more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="button" class="hover" value="Click" />
<div class="tooltip" style="display:none;">Tool tip Text</div>


$('.hover').mouseenter(function () {
    $(".tooltip").stop().fadeToggle(400, function () {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
$('.tooltip').mouseleave(function () {
    $(".tooltip").fadeToggle(400, function () {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

It will help you.

Comment: yes that´s what i have already in my fiddle but i wanted also that the tooltip stay if the user is over the tooltip. thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: code is changed, I think your requirement will meets